# Append and prepend header and trailer to file Unix/Mac

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I'm trying to prepend and append a header and trailer to a very large file.

So far I have tried sed and awk. Sed I can't get to work at all on the Mac with examples online. Awk I have go to work but only displaying to screen output.

Using this site as reference.

http://www.theunixschool.com/2011/03/different-ways-to-add-header-and.html

Using AWk how do I actually get this to update my file. Open to other suggestions too.

Comment: If you're happy with your awk command, you can combine it with part of Paul's solution: `awk stuff > tmp_file && mv tmp_file big_file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on unix/linux:

```
cat headerfile myfile trailerfile > newfile
```

Answer (score 4):

```
cat header big_file footer > tmp_file && mv tmp_file big_file
```